# Capture allotments used for unresolved cases in CRM

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there a way to capture minutes used from service activities performed under a case without resolving the case ( case status is active)?

I have a report that captures allotment details ( total allotments, remaining allotments, used allotments) from all resolved cases. But, I would also like to know how much time is being spent for activities whose case is still active.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out! I am new to this and learning!

Comment: How many Case statuses doe you Have?

Comment: I have one case for each month. So, typically the contract has 12 cases and each case has service activities under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate since the creation of the case or if you have the audit enabled since a specific state of case. Another option is you create new fields and create a plugin that when pass through a state calculate the minutes between the last state for example.

Comment: could you please explain this a little more? I am dabbling with the audit base option.

Comment: Audit feature enable you check when a property of entity was changed and by who. In this case you can know the difference of time between two states for example.